# UTF-8 Character encoding of Web-Essentials-generated (e.g. minified) files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, character-encoding, web-essentials

I have a javascript file encoded in UTF-8 (with BOM). I'd like its minified counterpart to also be UTF-8 with BOM. But whenever I update the original file, the generated one reverts to ANSI.

I've tried using Visual Studio to overwrite the generated file using my preferred encoding (as suggested by [TypeScript error Web essential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205199/typescript-error-web-essential)), but without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to force the minified files to save as UTF-8 with BOM by toggling on the "Save UTF-8 files with BOM" option:

```
Tools > Options > Web Essentials > Misc > Save UTF-8 files with BOM
```

Not sure how one would save as UTF-8 *without* BOM, but thankfully I don't need to.